# GET https://a.disquscdn.com/home/d-a60cd74/css/slick.css.map 404 (Not Found)

Tags: disqus

When I embedded the disqus comment universal code into my web site,
error occurred:

GET https://a.disquscdn.com/home/d-a60cd74/css/slick.css.map 404 (Not Found)

Where can I get this 'slick.css.map' file ?

What will be the best way to resolve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Discussed at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/disqus-dev/cVrYZv2P_jw/2SK2FTgHAGAJ

It appears to be related to css map files, which are, according to the link, debugging files.